# Simple transform distorting loop cuts

Tags: transforms

When I try extend the outermost edge of these panels using proportional editing (or simple transform for that matter) the loop cuts distort.

[image: loop_cuts_straight]

[image: loop_cuts_distorted]

Can someone help me understand why—and how to workaround it?

I imagine that because the faces on the curved end are simply longer, it becomes apparent if you try to transform the shape. Ok, makes sense. But I’ve tried messing around with the proportional editing settings, the transform orientation, and the pivot point to no avail. It seems that Blender *should* be able to understand that a user would want to stretch this shape along the desired axis without distorting the loops.

Thanks,

John

Comment: One thing I often do, is if you just want your loop cut to be straight, is just make a loop cut, and then just scale it to zero along its axis so it is straight. This isn't really a good workaround, but is often handy for me.

Comment: This worked great, I did some more research and this seems to be the best method I could find—and a great utility move.

Comment: Ok glad I could help. hopefully someday they will implement some loop cut options.

Comment: I just remembered another method to do it that might be useful, so i made an answer with both.

Comment: could you please share your file so that we understand what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets say i have this object that i want to make a straight loop cut in:

[image: start]

However, as you can see, this loop cut isn't straight, since the object isn't symmetrical.

**Option 1: Straighten out your loop cuts**

If you want your loop cuts to be flat along, say, the Y axis, then after selecting your loop cut, you can just do S > Y > 0 to make them flat in that axis.

[image: scale]

**Option 2: Bisect tool**

What if your object isn't aligned along the axis? What do you do then? Or what if you are just too lazy for a two step process?

Well then you can use the bisect tool.

Select your object, and using the search bar (or some other method), select bisect. Then, you can just drag where you want your cut to be, and it will make a loop cut along that line!

[image: bisect]

The one issue with this is that it is hard to get a perfectly aligned bisection because your cursor is imprecise, but option 1 can help with that.

Comment: Great advice, and thank you for opening my eyes to a new tool. Maybe you can hold control while bisecting to snap it to an axis? I’ll give it a shot and play around. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, i've tried snapping the bisect for a while, but have never been able to do it. do let me know if you find out how. (and you can accept this answer if you want to)